# PL/SQL and JDBC Commits: Does writing commit in PL/SQL commits to database even if i do conn.rollback in jdbc?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql

I am developing a project which does the following :

1. truncate a temporary table T1.
2. insert some thousand rows into temporary table T1.
3. Execute a procedure  which has some commit statements in it.
4. insert rows from table T1 to other identical table(with respect to structur) T2.
5. Execute 2 more procedures with commit statement in them.

Above 5 steps form one transaction to me. So either all should be done or none of them should be done.

Now even though i do conn.rollback if some error occurs few changes are getting reflected into database.

Is commit statement in procedures the reason ? Does truncating table implicitly commits to database ?

If yes ? What could be possible solution ?

Thanks in advance !!!

P.N. : Database is in oracle and i have less knowledge of PL/SQL

Comment: If you are calling procedures from another client, calling client should have commits or rollbacks rather than in stored procedures and thus you will have absolute control over your transactions.

Comment: So i will have to remove commit statements from my procedure. I will do that

Comment: What about truncate statements. Those are DDL. I think they will get committed even i dont do commit. Correct me if i am wrong !

Comment: Yes `TRUNCATE` does a commit and there by committing all previous transactions.

Comment: Use DELETE instead of TRUNCATE if you want transactional handling.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh All your 5 steps are asynchronous or synchronous? i.e. commit should be executed when all 5 steps are successful?

Comment: they should be executed in given order. I guess i got the answer. Thanks people :)

Comment: SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE BD_BIDS_APPR_DET' INTO V_SQL1 FROM DUAL;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL1;     .  Does execute immediate performs implicit commit ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Truncating the table (or doing any other DDL statement) causes an implicit commit before and after the statement is executed.  Committing in your procedures will also terminate your transaction.

If you really want all those steps to be part of a single transaction, you would need to remove the `TRUNCATE` (are you sure you really need that for a global temporary table?) and to remove the `commit` statements from your procedures.  In general, stored procedures should not contain transaction control statements for precisely this reason-- it makes it exceedingly difficult to reuse them if you want your transaction to encompass multiple different calls.

Comment: If only my backend developer knew this :/ . It took me 2 days to convince them. I was explaining them the same thing. Posted this question just to confirm if i am right. Because i have less knowledge about PL/SQL. Just the kind of answer i needed :)

Comment: SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE BD_BIDS_APPR_DET' INTO V_SQL1 FROM DUAL;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL1;     .  Does execute immediate performs implicit commit ?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh - `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` does not do an implicit commit.  Executing DDL (which requires the use of dynamic SQL in a stored procedure) does.